# Safari Array indexOf fails to find anything

Tags: javascript, safari

When I evaluate the following javascript in Safari 6.0:

```
Array.indexOf([1,2,3],3)
```

It returns -1, essentially saying that 3 is not in the array!

But in Firefox it correctly returns 2.

I know that Array.indexOf is a relatively new function so I have code that tests if it is present and if not defines it.  However it appears this function is built in to Safari.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Edit:  This is actually a simplified version of the problem.  What I am actually doing is trying to locate the index of a TD cell in a TR:

```
var tr = td.parentNode
var col = Array.indexOf(tr.cells,td)
```

`tr.cells` does not have an `indexOf`.  But, using `Array.indexOf` I can treat it as such, at least in Firefox.  In Safari this does not work.

I guess in this case I could actually use cellindex, but if that was not defined, how would I go about getting the index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm wondering why you don't use it like intended:

```
[1,2,3].indexOf( 3 );
```

Unless it's an academic question. In that case it's actually a <strike>bug</strike> special Firefox implementation. If you want to use the `Array.prototype` version directly, you should go like

```
Array.prototype.indexOf.call([1,2,3], 3);
```

Comment: Huh, that's a good question!  Apparently that was the way I saw it used in the first example I encountered it and it worked in Firefox so it just stuck.  Indeed it must be a "bug" in Firefox that this even works. The proper way you have pointed out works in Safari.

Comment: Well, why can't `indexOf` be a property of Array function itself? )

Comment: Ok, this works in my simplified question, but not in the original problem.  I am updating my question to reflect that.

Comment: @raina77ow: its not in the spec.

Comment: @jAndy Then I'd call it an undocumented feature perhaps. )

Comment: @raina77ow: Its pretty questionable if solo-attempts like these without W3C/ECMA resolution are very useful. I wouldn't call that "a feature".

Comment: @jAndy Yet I'd call it a question of perception. It's quite common for standard to implement these 'solo-attempts' - if they're reasonable. And how this particular one is different from, for example, `Object.keys`, I just don't know.

Comment: well, putting all the ES5 "object methods" into `Object.prototype` would have been asking for hell on earth. Since **every** object (including `Array`, `String`, `Number`, etc. etc.) would inherit from this. That was a wise decision. But for specific methods, its fine I think.